# Agregar multiples productos al carrito - React.js

Tags: reactjs

estoy tratando de agregar multiples productos al carrito en la sgte app de practica que estoy haciendo: [shoplit](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/). Practicamente solo me falta agregar multiples celulares al carrito cada vez que se haga clic en el boton Añadir al carrito. Tengo el siguiente componente que renderiza los productos en el carrito de compras:

```js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import './css/product-added.css';

class ShoppingCart extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Fragment> 
        { this.props.number > 0
        ?
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div className="product-added">
            
            <figure>
              <img loading="lazy" src={this.props.image} alt={this.props.titleProduct} title={this.props.titleProduct} />
            </figure>

            <div className="information-product-added">Se añadió al carrito {this.props.number} {this.props.titleProduct}.

              <span>Total a pagar: $/. {this.props.price}</span>

              <button className="buy"><Icon iconName="fas fa-shopping-cart" iconStyle={{padding: 0, color: 'black'}} />&nbsp;Comprar</button>

              <Icon iconName="fas fa-trash-alt trash" iconTitle="Eliminar" onClick={e => {
              e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
              this.props.hideInformation();
              }} />

            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="buy-all"><Icon iconName="fas fa-shopping-cart" iconStyle={{padding: 0, color:'black'}} />&nbsp;&nbsp;Comprar todo</button>
      </div>

        :
        
        <h4 style={{margin: 0}}>Ningún producto ha sido añadido al carrito...&nbsp;<Icon iconName="fas fa-sad-tear" iconStyle={{padding: 0}} /></h4>
      }
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default ShoppingCart;
```

Este componente lo renderizo en el componente Header:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/header.css';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart';

class Header extends Component{
  state = {
    currentWindow: undefined
  }

  render(){
    const { image, number, titleProduct, price } = this.props;
    return(

        { this.state.currentWindow === 4
        ? <Information
        title="Carrito de compras"
        close={this.closeInformation}
        innerHTML={
        <ShoppingCart
        image={image}
        price={price}
        number={number}
        titleProduct={titleProduct}
        hideInformation={this.props.hideInformation}
        /> }
        />
        : null
        }
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

He cortado el componente para que sea más fácil de leer, ahora este componente lo renderizo en el componente App:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from '../header/Header.js';

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    productsAdded: false,
    image: undefined,
    number: 0,
    price: 0,
    titleProduct: undefined
  }

  /* Mostrar el número de productos agregados */

  numberProductsAdded = () => {
    this.setState({
      productsAdded: true
    })
  }
  
  /* Muestra la informacion de los productos en el carrito de compras */

  setInformation = (image, number, price, titleProduct) => {
    this.setState({
      image: image,
      number: this.state.number + Number(number),
      price: Number(price) * Number(number),
      titleProduct: titleProduct
    })
  }

/* Muestra un mensaje de no se han agregado productos si el estado de number es 0 */

  hideInformation = () =>{
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('product-added').length === 0){
      this.setState({
        number: 0
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <Header
        onSearch={this.search}
        changeTextNotFound={this.changeTextNotFound}
        productsAdded={this.state.productsAdded}
        image={this.state.image}
        number={this.state.number}
        price={this.state.price}
        titleProduct={this.state.titleProduct}
        hideInformation={this.hideInformation}
        />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Bueno debe agregarme sólo un producto en el carrito de compras, Ejm: le doy en añadir al carrito en samsung galaxy a20 con una cantidad de 3 productos ( o sino otra que se puede especificar en el input number).

Me debe agregar solo un producto y la cantidad que elegiste debe mostrarse en: `Se añadió al carrito (Numero especificado de productos)`, no debe agregar 3 productos de ese mismo celular, sino un producto y la cantidad se especifica dentro del carrito, espero se pueda entender lo que intento hacer.

El máximo numero de productos añadidos al carrito debe ser 60, la longitud de celulares que muestro, por eso cada vez que se hace click en añadir al carrito solo debe agregar uno, con su respectiva informacion de este: nombre del producto, cantidad y precio, solo necesito ayuda en eso.

Estaba pensando en usar `appendChild()` pero creo que no seria una buena forma de hacerlo en React, entonces como puedo agregar simultaneamente productos al carrito con lo especificado arriba, gracias !

Aqui pueden ver los componentes de la [app](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado tu problema, podrías ir validando la entrada de los nuevos productos según su modelo por ejemplo. Entonces, si el usuario agrega 5 productos de un celular particular, agregas el elemento nuevo a una variable que se encargará de almacenar el producto siempre y cuando NO exista en ésta.

Un ejemplo

```
const addShopCart = (item, quantity) => {
   const aux = shoppingCart.find((x) => x.model === item.modelo);

   if (!aux) {
      const cellphone = {
         model: item.modelo,
         unitPrice: item.precio,
         quantity: quantity,
         totalPrice: item.precio * quantity
      };
      setShoppingCart([...shoppingCart, cellphone]);
   }
};
```

Entonces, la constante aux te dirá si el elemento existe en tu carrito o no. Si no existe lo agrega.

Te dejo un **[ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/contador-de-productos-en-carrito-xhro0)** práctico para que lo analices.

Nos comentas que tal te va!

Comment: Muchas gracias bro ! pude resolver y ahora agrega perfectamente al carrito, esto me ayudara para la casilla de gastos !